# Which interface linux will use between eth0 and eth0.1?

Tags: linux, interface, ubuntu-12.04

I have a `VPS`  on which eth0 is configured  , i want to configure a interface eth0.1 but i want to know if i will configure this new interface the data flow will be divided between eth0 and eth0.1 ?

I want to use `eth0 Ip address` for all the data flow on server like custom written scripts and `eth0.1 Ip address` to access it from browser as i have web-server on it.

Comment: Are you talking about a secondary IP address or VLAN tag?  `eth0.1` is usually used for the latter...

Comment: yes i want to add secondary IP address on linux @BenVoigt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a secondary IP address you use the `:` separator on the interface name. Suppose you have eth0 assigned with 11.22.33.44 and you also want it to work with 11.22.33.55. Then you would just do:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 11.22.33.55
```

If you don't touch routing through the `ip route` command, 11.22.33.55 won't ever be used as an outbound interface, unless you're answering a request that points to 11.22.33.55 itself, so there are two more things to do.

The first is setting up your webserver's listening address to 11.22.33.55 instead of 'any' IP or 11.22.33.44. This depends on your webserver, in the case of apache check out the [Listen directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen).

The second thing, if you use a domain, to do is setting up a DNS record to point to 11.22.33.55 instead of 11.22.33.44. Take care because a domain name can't be resolved to a different address depending on the destination port, so you'll need a domain name for each interface. The alternative is directly using the IP address 11.22.33.44 for the script stuff and using the domain name for the webserver only.

After you've done this you can safely use tcpdump, iptables & friends on both the physical and the virtual interface.

Answer (score 2):

Linux, by default, will send all packets out the default interface for the subnet, which is most likely `eth0`.

`iproute2` attempts to solve this problem by redirecting packets out on the same interface on which they have been received.

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2

So, to answer your question, most packets on your system will *probably* already go out `eth0` (assuming it's the same subnet).

If you set up an `alias` interface, `eth0.1` (from your example), any programs listening on either *all* interfaces, or specifically, to `eth0.1` will be able to receive packets on that IP address.